# Font family and font size is not updating in ngx-summernote, after paste the content

Tags: angular16

Font family and font size is not updating after paste the content in the in ngx-summernote in angular 16 project

In the angular 16 project, we used ngx-summernote package to generate the document content.
we are changing the font family and font size, but it is not updating.

Technologies used :

- angular - 16,
- ngx-summernote - 1.0.0